# what library to use with ESP32 to configure a telegram bot?

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp32

hello stack overflow community.

i want to finish my graduation project, but am having trouble in the ESP32 coding.

i am making a smart safe box
the program should do the following:

1. allow the user to open the safe door via keypad
2. allow the user to open the safe door via RFID
3. the safe is connected to a telegram bot, to make it possible to open the safe via telegram, and also receive the state of the safe box ( Door opened, door closed, wrong password entered, etc )

this is the code i did:

```
#include <Keypad.h> // Include the Keypad library
#include <WiFi.h> // Include the WiFi library
#include <UniversalTelegramBot.h> // Include the UniversalTelegramBot library
#include <MFRC522.h> // Include the MFRC522 library

#define SS_PIN 5 // Define the SS pin for the MFRC522 RFID sensor
#define RST_PIN 23 // Define the RST pin for the MFRC522 RFID sensor
#define LED_PIN 2 // Define the LED pin
#define BUZZER_PIN 4 // Define the buzzer pin
#define DOOR_PIN 16 // Define the pin for the door
const byte ROWS = 4; // Define the number of rows in the keypad
const byte COLS = 4; // Define the number of columns in the keypad
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = { // Define the keys in the keypad
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {14, 27, 26, 25}; // Define the row pins for the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {33, 32, 35, 34}; // Define the column pins for the keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS); // Create a Keypad object

const char* ssid = "your_SSID"; // Replace with your WiFi network name
const char* password = "your_PASSWORD"; // Replace with your WiFi network password
const char* token = "6063247261:AAE-dCDewFBwZLQQzw_TwVpp40C8plhMhko"; // Replace with your Telegram bot token
const int chat_id = 594170852; // Replace with your Telegram chat ID
//WiFiClientSecure client; // Create a secure WiFi client
//UniversalTelegramBot bot(token, client); // Create a UniversalTelegramBot object

MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create an MFRC522 object
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key; // Create an MFRC522 MIFARE key object

int state = 0; // Initialize the state variable
String password_str = ""; // Initialize the password string
bool door_opened = false; // Initialize the door_opened boolean

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Start the serial communication
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT); // Set the LED pin as an output
  pinMode(BUZZER_PIN, OUTPUT); // Set the buzzer pin as an output
  pinMode(DOOR_PIN, OUTPUT); // Set the door pin as an output
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW); // Turn off the LED
  digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, LOW); // Turn off the buzzer
  digitalWrite(DOOR_PIN, LOW); // Close the door
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password); // Connect to the WiFi network
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { // Wait for the WiFi connection to be established
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  SPI.begin(); // Initialize the SPI bus
  rfid.PCD_Init(); // Initialize the MFRC522 RFID sensor
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // Initialize the MIFARE key
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }
}

void loop() {
  switch (state) {
    case 0:
      password_str = ""; // Reset the password string
      Serial.println("Enter password:");
      state = 1; // Move to the next state
      break;
    case 1:
      char key_pressed = keypad.getKey(); // Read the key pressed on the keypad
      if (key_pressed != NO_KEY) { // If a key is pressed
        if (key_pressed == '#') { // If the '#' key is pressed
          if (password_str == "1234") { // If the password is correct
            Serial.println("Password correct");
            open_door(); // Open the door
            state = 2; // Move to the next state
          } else { // If the password is incorrect
            Serial.println("Password incorrect");
            buzz(); // Buzz the buzzer
            state = 0; // Reset the state
          }
        } else { // If a number key is pressed
          password_str += key_pressed; // Add the key to the password string
        }
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (door_opened) { // If the door has been opened
        send_telegram_message("Door opened via keypad"); //Send a message to the Telegram chat to notify the user that the door has been opened via the keypad
        door_opened = false; // Reset the door_opened boolean
      }
      state = 3; // Move to the next state
      break;
    case 3:
      if (bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1)) { // Check for incoming Telegram messages
        handle_telegram_message(); // Handle the incoming message
      }
      break;
  }
  if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { // If an RFID card is detected
    if (authenticate_card()) { // If the card is authenticated
      Serial.println("Card authenticated");
      open_door(); // Open the door
      send_telegram_message("Door opened via RFID"); // Send a message to the Telegram chat to notify the user that the door has been opened via RFID
      delay(5000); // Wait for 5 seconds
      door_opened = false; // Reset the door_opened boolean
    } else { // If the card is not authenticated
      Serial.println("Card authentication failed");
      buzz(); // Buzz the buzzer
    }
    rfid.PICC_HaltA(); // Halt the RFID tag
    rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1(); // Stop the crypto1 process
  }
}

void open_door() {
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // Turn on the LED
  digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, HIGH); // Turn on the buzzer
  digitalWrite(DOOR_PIN, HIGH); // Open the door
  delay(5000); // Wait for 5 seconds
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW); // Turn off the LED
  digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, LOW); // Turn off the buzzer
  digitalWrite(DOOR_PIN, LOW); // Close the door
  door_opened = true; // Set the door_opened boolean to true
}

void buzz() {
  digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, HIGH); // Turn on the buzzer
  delay(500); // Wait for 0.5 seconds
  digitalWrite(BUZZER_PIN, LOW); // Turn off the buzzer
}

bool authenticate_card() {
  MFRC522::StatusCode status;
  byte buffer[18];
  byte size = sizeof(buffer);
  status = rfid.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, 1, &key, &(rfid.uid)); // Authenticate the card using the MIFARE key
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    return false;
  }
  status = rfid.MIFARE_Read(1, buffer, &size); // Read the card data
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

void handle_telegram_message() {
  for (int i = 0; i < bot.message_count(); i++) { // Loop through all the incoming messages
    String chat_text = bot.messages[i].text; // Get the message text
    int chat_from = bot.messages[i].from_id; // Get the chat ID
    if (chat_text == "/open" && chat_from == chat_id) { // If the message is "/open" and the chat ID is correct
      Serial.println("Door opened via telegram");
      open_door(); // Open the door
      send_telegram_message("Door opened via telegram"); // Send a message to the Telegram chat to notify the user that the door has been opened via Telegram
    }
  }
}

void send_telegram_message(String message) {
  bot.sendMessage(chat_id, message); // Send a message to the Telegram chat
}
```

the errors am getting :

```
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino: In function 'void loop()':
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:83:10: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
     case 2:
          ^
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:66:12: note:   crosses initialization of 'char key_pressed'
       char key_pressed = keypad.getKey(); // Read the key pressed on the keypad
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:90:10: error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
     case 3:
          ^
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:66:12: note:   crosses initialization of 'char key_pressed'
       char key_pressed = keypad.getKey(); // Read the key pressed on the keypad
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:91:11: error: 'bot' was not declared in this scope
       if (bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1)) { // Check for incoming Telegram messages
           ^~~
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:91:11: note: suggested alternative: 'bit'
       if (bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1)) { // Check for incoming Telegram messages
           ^~~
           bit
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino: In function 'void handle_telegram_message()':
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:145:23: error: 'bot' was not declared in this scope
   for (int i = 0; i < bot.message_count(); i++) { // Loop through all the incoming messages
                       ^~~
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:145:23: note: suggested alternative: 'bit'
   for (int i = 0; i < bot.message_count(); i++) { // Loop through all the incoming messages
                       ^~~
                       bit
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino: In function 'void send_telegram_message(String)':
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:157:3: error: 'bot' was not declared in this scope
   bot.sendMessage(chat_id, message); // Send a message to the Telegram chat
   ^~~
D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:157:3: note: suggested alternative: 'bit'
   bot.sendMessage(chat_id, message); // Send a message to the Telegram chat
   ^~~
   bit
Compilation error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]
```

any help please.

i tried talking to chatgpt but nothing were helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As a student, it is important to ask the right question, the question to the problem you are facing is not "what library to use...", but why do you get those error messages, what does it means? how to solve it? It is also equally import to read the error message and try to understand what it is means, your error log basically consists of two issues.

> Compilation error: jump to case label [-fpermissive]

This one is often not so obvious and puzzle to the programmers who are new to C++, so I'd like to explain here. In `case 1`, you had a declarative statement where you declare a `key_pressed` variable:

```cpp
    char key_pressed = keypad.getKey(); // Read the key pressed on the keypad
```

According to [c++ documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch):

> ***if a declaration statement is encountered inside the statement, it has to be scoped in its own compound statement***

So to solve this issue, you need to encapsulate the code within the `case 1` with a pair of `{` and `}` to limit the scope of the declaration is only within the scope of `case 1`.

```cpp
case 1:
    {
      char key_pressed = keypad.getKey(); // Read the key pressed on the keypad
      if (key_pressed != NO_KEY) { // If a key is pressed
        if (key_pressed == '#') { // If the '#' key is pressed
          if (password_str == "1234") { // If the password is correct
            Serial.println("Password correct");
            open_door(); // Open the door
            state = 2; // Move to the next state
          } else { // If the password is incorrect
            Serial.println("Password incorrect");
            buzz(); // Buzz the buzzer
            state = 0; // Reset the state
          }
        } else { // If a number key is pressed
          password_str += key_pressed; // Add the key to the password string
        }
      }
    }
    break;
```

> D:\Study\Study\senior project 2\smartsafecode\smartsafecode.ino:91:11: note: suggested alternative: 'bit'
> if (bot.getUpdates(bot.last_message_received + 1)) { // Check for incoming Telegram messages
> ^~~

This is the second error that you are facing, this is because you comment out the line `//UniversalTelegramBot bot(token, client);` so `bot` doesn't exist. In order to instantiate an `bot` object, you need to include two libraries:

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>

...
WiFiClientSecure client;
UniversalTelegramBot bot(token, client);
```

Your code may have other error popping up after you fixing those errors, but you should be able to solve it yourself. Happy coding and good luck to your graduation project.

Comment: ty for your feedback, that was helpful.
about the title unfortunally i tried every possible question that relate to my problem, but all of them weren't accepted.